# VMware VM run on insecure OS

Tags: windows, linux

I run VMware with Linux through my Windows OS. I want to use the Linux VM for online transactions. Is it possible for a virus, spy or worm to attack my Linux VM from the Windows host? Is my Linux environment the same secure clean Linux installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible for a virus/worm to attack on your host to attack the guest OS?  Yes.  Is it likely?  No.

Malware can do anything you can do, including writing to the virtual disk.  The easiest route would be to simply mount the virtual machine drive, and write new malware to it. This is unlikely because it would take specially crafted code to exploit this.  It's unlikely that malware writers would care about this rare corner case.  Malware is about volume, not targeting individuals.  Unless someone is specifically after you, it's not a serious concern.

What is very easy is running a keylogger on the host OS.  A keylogger on the host OS would still be able to log keystrokes on the guest, since all keystrokes still go through the host OS and the guest OS is just another application running on the host.

So a virtual machine can't protect you in any way from keyloggers.

Comment: A slight exception to this rule exists, if the guest OS is given the ability to talk to the hardware directly and operate within the VMX root domain. Microsoft has a couple of papers on tools they're developing to run software on (untrusted OS; trusted hardware) environments but afaik, no software yet. See Drawbridge (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/drawbridge/) and Haven (https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi14/osdi14-paper-baumann.pdf)

Comment: @SteveDL  Interesting.  Though I'd be a bit leery of giving a VM direct access to hardware.

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer:**
Yes, both the host (in your case Windows) and the guest (in your case Linux) OS can be attacked by malware.

**Additional Details:**
In fact - with techniques like "[Red Pill and Blue Pill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(software))" (like in the Matrix movie) it is possible for malware to bypass the barrier of virtualization and proliferate on the host or hypervisor.

So please follow defense in depth!

Comment: Yes there is - you should consider some reading yourself - click on that link that you edited and read about the red pill.

Red pill is a technique to identify the presence of a virtual environment and thus giving the malware means to take decisions like deactivating to prevent research or exploit other vulnerabilities so as to escape the guest OS.

Comment: I give you credit for pointing out specifically on the Blue pill though would have appreciated you being a bit more civil about it. You conveniently edited out "red" from the post (and deleting related comments) and you do agree it is to detect as I explained above. This detection can and is used for the evasion and subsequent infection of the host OS.

Comment: To sum my concerns: Red Pill doesn't exist. Blue Pill doesn't apply to the question.